# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance in vue

Tags: vue.js

im using [Vue-infinite-loading](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/guide/start-with-hn.html)
for creating infinite pagination with laravel.this is my component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="card" v-for="(i, $index) in items" :key="$index">
      ...
    </div>
    <infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>
</template>

<script>
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';
const api = './api';
export default {
    components: { InfiniteLoading },
    data: () => ({
        keywords: null,
        items: [],
        page: 1,
        per_page: 10,
        last_page: null,
    }),
    methods: {
        infiniteHandler($state) {
          axios.get(api, {
            params: {
              page: this.page,
            },
          }).then(response => {
            this.last_page = response.data.last_page;
            if (this.last_page != this.page) {
              this.page = this.page + 1;
              this.items.push(...response.data.data);
              $state.loaded();
            } else {
              $state.complete();
            }
            })
        },
    }
    };
</script>
```

this works fine in page 1,but when i scroll to bottom of page,i get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
    at _nonIterableSpread
    at _toConsumableArray
```

Comment: `...response.data.data` is not spreadable. Check into that data struct.

Comment: If `response.data.data` is already an array you can just do `this.items = response.data.data`